# MFMailComposeViewController is acctually a navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, messageui

When I try to push my MFMailComposeViewController it says I can't push navigation controllers?! Hmm... dunno about that.

Basically all my view controllers are actually subclasses of CustomUIViewController which automatically removes the title view from the navigation bar (as I have a logo in the navigation bar instead).

Presenting my MFMailComposeViewController modally puts the title back in there because I can't make it subclass CustomUIViewController (or can i? I dunno?).

So I really need a way to remove the title view from the MFMailComposeViewController.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: “Inherits from UINavigationController : UIViewController : UIResponder : NSObject” — http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/

Comment: lol, thanks- why is it called the MFMailComposeViewController then?! :p

Comment: It's called like that because it is subclass of  UINavigationController ^^.

Comment: Because it's the view controller for the mail-composing view. It is a kind of navigation controller, and a navigation controller is a kind of view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few easy options:

- Subclass MFMailComposeViewController too.
- Don't subclass CustomUIViewController; override some methods in a category of UIViewController (icky).
- Hide the title item in a category of UINavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

Considering the title view contains the Cancel and Send buttons, I'm not sure you'd want to remove it. You could try changing the actual title in the navigation bar with

`mailController.navigationItem.titleView = myLogo;`

Which should set that center area of the nav item to be your logo instead of some text.

Comment: Perhaps 'mailcontroller.topViewController.navigationItem.titleView = myTitleView;'

Comment: The title view is presumably the one in the middle; the cancel and send buttons are leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem.

Answer (score -1):

Although it would be nice to get more control over the appearance, I don't think there is a clean method.  When you can't change it, I think you should hide it:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor clearColor], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:UITextAttributeTextColor, nil]]];
```